# Can you use Routes on Structure entries

Tags: structure, routing

I'm using a route to use a different template, but whatever I try the page remains unchanged, my structure is set as:

entry url format: {slug}

entry template: _pages/_entry

I want an entry's slug to use a different template - would this possibly be affecting the route being followed?

I want the entry 'home' to use the 'index' template (and not the '_home' template which exists at _pages/_home)

I've cleared my cache and updated indexes

Comment: I used {% redirect "/" %}

will think of a better way, but for parent entries in a structure where they are just used for the structure and need no content, e.g. 

ABOUT (no content)
team
history

is there a way of redirecting say ABOUT to team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know you can do things like this in your root entry  template to load it dynamically based on slug or entry type

```
{% extends [
  'pages/_custom/' ~ page.slug ~ '.twig',
  'pages/_entrytypes/' ~ page.type ~ '.twig',
  'pages/_generic.twig' ]
%}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does each line actually do assuming thats in _entry.twig?
and assuming the templates reside in the /pages directory? A brief overview of the functionality would be invaluable :)

Comment: Say that you have an entry with the type `page` and the slug `slug`. It would first try to load `pages/_custom/slug.twig` - if that doesn't exist it would try to load `pages/_entrytypes/page.twig` - and, finally, it would fall back to `pages/_generic.twig`